# How to generate EF entities from DB in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, function, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use EF with Azure Functions in Visual Studio using C#. I have installed EF through NuGet.

However when I tried to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project, I couldn't find it under New Item -> Visual C# Items -> Data like with web and console projects.

How does one do this? Is it supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one do this? Is it supported?

I assume that you create **.net core azure function** project. It is not related to azure function. If you create the .net framework azure function project. It could be done.

In the .net core project, create the EF model based on your existing database. We will be using some **Entity Framework Tools to create a model from the database**. So we will install the tools package as well:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Detail info you could refer to [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model)

- Tools –> NuGet Package Manager –> Package Manager Console
- Run the following command to create a model from the existing database:

---

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was like duh. I'm new to Azure development.